# Python Lambda Comparing Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, amazon-ec2, lambda

I have some code here to compare two dictionaries using Lambda and filter. Basically I have a required Tags dictionary and a Tags Dictionary for each EC2 Instance.

I need to be able to process two conditions. The first condition is only check whether the all the Keys in Required Tags exist in Instance Tags and they are not blank.

```
requiredTags = {'Name' : ['WebSense','NAT-V2'] }
instanceTags = i['Instances'][0]['Tags']
requiredTagsPresent = filter(lambda x: x['Key'] in requiredTags and 
x['Value'] is not '', instanceTags)
```

The next condition is the most common - check whethere all the keys and their corresponding values are

```
requiredTagsPresent = filter(lambda x: x['Key'] in requiredTags and x['Value'] in requiredTags, instanceTags)
```

So far, I haven't been able to accomplish both of the above in a single script. 
The last condition is the one I am having trouble with. I want to have a specific tag value that if present, we only check for the existence of the corresponding key regardless of the value. I have no idea how to do something like that.

Any tips?

Comment: This is not clear.  If you can't accomplish them both in one script, can you accomplish each one in separate scripts?  Can you show us how you do that?  What is the type of `instance_tags` and what does it look like?

Comment: Instance_Tags is another dictionary. It looks like this. [{'Key' : 'Name' }, {'Value' : 'j' } - so the tag is name=j

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is much easier to do if you use the built-in function `all` rather than `lambda` and `filter`.  To check if all the keys in required_tags exist in instance_tags and they are not blank, use:

```
all_present = all(k in instance_tags and instance_tags[k] for k in required_tags.keys())
```

To check whether all the keys and values in instance_tags are in required_tags, use:

```
all_present2 = all(k in required_tags and v in required_tags for k, v in instance_tags.items())
```

This assumes Python3.

But I am not sure this is what you want, since your description of the second test condition has words left off at the end: "check whethere [sic] all the keys and their corresponding values are ".  Are what?  Also, when you told me in your comment what the structure of instance_tags was, you had unmatched square brackets.  You said it was a dictionary but it looks like a list of dictionaries, each containing one item.